# How can I pause execution within a method until the user sends a "Did End on Exit" (presses the "Next" button on the keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This is what I have:

```
while(wordList){                  //wordlist is instance of NSArray containing NSStrings
    word.text = [wordList objectAtIndex:x]; //word is instance of UILabel

    //LOOKING TO PLACE WAIT CODE HERE TO WAIT FOR "DID END ON EXIT"

    input = inputBox.text; //input is instance of UITextField

    [self compare:input andb:word.text]; //compare is an instance method to compare the two strings
    x++;
}
```

I'm a beginner, if any of you could help me, that would be fantastic.

Best...
SL

Comment: So you want to **start** the execution after the user taps next on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(yourMethod:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

**Edit**:

Why don't you just break the while loop and call a separate method when the user hits next? No need to pause and trigger some other method.

Comment: Hm...Unfortunately it zipped through the loop without giving the user the time to press the Next button. Any other ideas to pause execution to wait for the user? Thanks. Best...SL

Comment: Also I have this included in XCode, forgot to post here; inputBox has already been sent becomeFirstResponder...Thanks

Comment: When I use this snippet and call a method, my textField that has already become first responder resigns first responder...without me telling it to. No matter where I call the method [myTextfield becomeFirstResponder] it never works...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're asking about won't work. If your app were to pause execution in the middle of a method, what would cause it to unpause?

The user is not going to be entering text in the middle of your loop -- that would have to have already done that before the loop starts to execute. Trigger the method that contains the loop as @Imirak suggested, or from some other user interaction, for example a button press. That way you'll know that the user has already entered the text, and the code you've written should work as expected.

One note though: the code you've shown doesn't check the return value from your `compare:andb:` method. You haven't really provided enough information about what you expect the method to do to do to be sure whether that makes sense or not.

Also, your loop control logic is incorrect -- as written it's either going to be an infinite loop or it will never be entered, depending on whether `wordList` is `nil`. Consider using fast enumeration syntax instead of writing a `while` loop, for example:

```
for (UILabel *currLabel in wordList)
{
    // It appears as though this may be the comparison you want to do
    // but there's not enough context in your question to be sure.
    //
    if ([inputBox.text isEqualToString:currLabel.text])
    {
        // Do something here. Again, it's not clear what you're trying to do.   
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the method that Imirak suggested, is there any way to pass a nil sender object as a parameter for "yourMethod" ? The method I would like to call is an action method that is passed a sender object...can I pass nil using the method Imirak suggested? Thanks

Comment: You can't pass an argument to an action method; the sender of the message passes itself in as the argument (which is why the name of the parameter is `sender`). If you don't need an argument to be passed in, rewrite the method to not take a parameter. If you do that, make sure you remove the colon character from the name of the selector in your code (i.e., `@selector(yourMethod)` instead of `@selector(yourMethod:)`).